# BigQuery approx_quantiles WHERE, using a different WHERE for different functions

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a table and we are trying to compute quantiles for different columns in the table:

```
with t1 as (
    select 'a' as category, 0.25 as stat1, 2 as stat1ct, 0.82 as stat2, 3 as stat2ct union all
    select 'a' as category, 0.35 as stat1, 4 as stat1ct, 0.68 as stat2, 5 as stat2ct union all
    select 'a' as category, 0.45 as stat1, 3 as stat1ct, 0.74 as stat2, 4 as stat2ct union all
    select 'a' as category, 0.28 as stat1, 0 as stat1ct, 0.72 as stat2, 0 as stat2ct union all
    select 'a' as category, 0.36 as stat1, 0 as stat1ct, 0.65 as stat2, 4 as stat2ct union all
    select 'a' as category, 0.63 as stat1, 1 as stat1ct, 0.53 as stat2, 3 as stat2ct union all
    select 'a' as category, 0.18 as stat1, 5 as stat1ct, 0.52 as stat2, 1 as stat2ct union all
    select 'a' as category, 0.43 as stat1, 3 as stat1ct, 0.57 as stat2, 2 as stat2ct
)

select
    approx_quantiles(stat1, 100) as atr2FgPct
    ,approx_quantiles(stat2, 100) as paint2FgPct
from t1
```

and this works fine. However, we would like to edit this by filtering **each column** based on a WHERE criteria using another column. We are looking for something like this:

```
select
    approx_quantiles(stat1 where stat1ct > 2, 100) as atr2FgPct
    ,approx_quantiles(stat2 where stat2ct > 2, 100) as paint2FgPct
from t1
```

...where `stat1` quantiles are based only on the `stat1` values where `stat1ct` is greater than 2. If `stat1ct` is less than 2, then the value for `stat1` should not count towards the quantiles. Is this possible to do in bigquery?

Answer (score 3):

Consider below approach

```
select
   approx_quantiles(if(stat1ct > 2, stat1, null), 100) as atr2FgPct
  ,approx_quantiles(if(stat2ct > 2, stat2, null), 100) as paint2FgPct
from t1
```

Note: APPROX_QUANTILES supports IGNORE NULLS and RESPECT NULLS

> If IGNORE NULLS is specified, the NULL values are excluded from the result. If RESPECT NULLS is specified, the NULL values are included in the result. If neither is specified, the NULL values are excluded from the result. An error is raised if an array in the final query result contains a NULL element.